# define NHibernate mappings in different assembly than the domain objects

Tags: nhibernate-mapping

I have an assembly *Foo.Bar* that holds all my domain logic and my domain object (e.g. `public class Project`, `public interface IProjectRepository`).

I also have an assembly *Foo.Bar.Data* that acts as my NHinbernate data access layer wich holds the `IProjectRepository` NHibernate-based implementation. It references *Foo.Bar* and contains the mapping files such as *Project.hbm.xml*.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="Foo.Bar"
                   namespace="Foo.Bar.Domain" default-lazy="false">
  <class name="Project">
    <id name="Id" column="ID" />
    <property name="Customer" column="CUSTOMER" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Unfortunately with this setup I get the following exception:

**NHibernate.MappingException : No persister for: Foo.Bar.Domain.Project**

And the NHibernate log says:

**WARN NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration (null) - No mapped documents found in assembly: Foo.Bar, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null**

Howver if I add the mapping file to the *Foo.Bar* assmbly everything works fine. But I really do not want any data access or NHinbernate implementation details into my domain assembly. This tends to be best practise, right? Is this kind of setup not a good way to go?

How can I make NHibernate find the mapping files in the *Foo.Bar.Data** assembly?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out that all I have to do is add

```
<mapping assembly="Foo.Bar.Data"/>
```

to my hibnerate configuration within the `<session-factory>` element.