# NHibernate and SQL Server datetime2 and supporting both SQL Server and Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

We have a project that uses NHibernate as the ORM. The project is designed to work on both SQL Server and Oracle (depending on the choices of the companies where the product is install). **We need to support both SQL Server and Oracle**.

In some cases we need to save DateTime fields with milliseconds so on Oracle the column type is `Date` and on SQL Server we use `datetime2`.

This is an example hbm:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="NHibernateDatetimeTest" namespace="NHibernateDatetimeTest">
  <class name="User" table="Users">
    <id name="UserId" column="ID" type="int">
    </id>

    <property name="Name" column="NAME" />
    <property name="RegistratrionDate" column="RegDate" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

When selecting from the database, all dates are presented as they should.

However, when I insert new data to SQL Server the date is saved without milliseconds. But if I change my hbm and specifying a type it work fine on SQL Server:

```
<property name="RegistratrionDate" column="RegDate" type="datetime2" />
```

The problem is that Oracle doesn't know what datetime2 is and throws an exception.

Is there any way to support both platforms and still have SQL Server save milliseconds?

Comment: Oracle DATE is up to second precision only.For higher precision your need to use TIMESTAMP data type.

Comment: @Husqvik - Sorry, but that wasn't my question. I need to support datetime2 of SQL Server but without explicitly specifying the datetime2 type in the hbm.

Comment: what version of NHibernate are you using?  Could you move to mapping by code?  If you can, you could split your mappings to separate assemblies and load the correct one for the environment (Oracle vs. SqlServer)

Comment: @Fran we're using version 4. Mapping in code is not an option. Is there any conditional mapping for hbm?

Comment: What about doing the same with the hbm's?  create 2 assemblies, copy your hbm's to both projects.  make your db specific changes.  See this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11086496/define-nhibernate-mappings-in-different-assembly-than-the-domain-objects) on how to configure mappings in different assemblies.

Comment: @Fran we thought about it. But it's a big project with many hbm's so we figured maintaining might be an issue and lead to bugs.

Comment: I'm not sure you have any other options.

Answer (score 1):

With NHibernate 4.x or previous, you would need to use a custom type relying on some ad-hoc setting changed according to target database for handling the switch between Oracle `timestamp` and SQL Server `datetime2`.

NHibernate 5.0, released some days ago, has quite changed its date-time handling, and will now do that for you automatically with the default NHibernate `DateTimeType` (which does no more cut fractional seconds by the way).

So in your mapping, just cease specifying any type for your date-time properties: its inference from the entity property .Net type should be enough.

See its [release notes](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/releases/tag/5.0.0) for more details, those changes are highlighted in the (long) possible breaking changes section.

> - NHibernate type DateTimeType, which is the default for a .Net DateTime, does no longer cut fractional seconds. Use DateTimeNoMsType if you wish to have fractional seconds cut. It applies to its Local/Utc counterparts too.

...

> - SQL Server 2008+ dialects now use datetime2 instead of datetime for all date-time types, including timestamp. This can be reverted with sql_types.keep_datetime setting.